# CritTeXt -- any sign of life?

Tags: context, ledmac

I've been fascinated by the [announcements of the upcoming features of CritTeXt in 2007](http://meeting.contextgarden.net/2007/share/idris/cr-apparatus.pdf).

As I learned from [a thread on NTG-context from early 2010](http://archive.contextgarden.net/message/20100218.072221.532e5bc3.en.html) we shouldn't expect a dedicated package, but that ConTeXt will eventually incorporate the needed functionalities.

I've been wondering:

- Is there anything happening on this front?
- When will things be up and running for non-ConTeXt-wizards to try out?
- Will there eventually be a "how-to" for critical editing in ConTeXt?

Comment: AFAIK, Idris Hamid does not read this forum. So, the best will be to ask him directly (or perhaps, ask on the ConTeXt mailing list). It is possible that, as with a lot of TeX projects, Idris no longer has the time to work on this project. Another option is to ask (either here or on the context mailing list which has more context users) how to achieve specific features for critical editions to know ConTeXt already has those features or not.

Comment: thanks, Aditya! That was more or less, what D.~Stender did last year without direct response from Idris Hamid (second link above). Asking the question here to a broader forum I hope to gather information from others who might have heard something or who might be involved in this project in one way or another or who have collected the bits and pieces and got them working on their own. Judging from the examples in the pdf it is already possible to some quite impressive editions with ConTeXt -- if anybody has succeeded in this, I'd love them to share their experiences.

Comment: @Florian - when it comes to ConTeXt, I guess the 'broader audience' is on the mailing list, not here. Yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have contributed to the document you linked to and have been doing some work in this area, so just a few pointers:

> Is there anything happening on this front?

Yes there is.

> When will things be up and running for non-ConTeXt-wizards to try out?

Development is driven by demand. It is highly unlikely that some ready-made module for "non-wizards" will be available any time.

> Will there eventually be a "how-to" for critical editing in ConTeXt?

IMHO, that's asking for the impossible. There is no such thing as "critical editing," there are hundreds of different traditions in different fields. Again, development is driven by demand - if you can come up with clear and reasonable specs, it is possible that ConTeX can already do some of the things you want and that others can be implemented easily. But given that those demands are almost without limits, no-one will just sit down for the heck of it and try to come up with a universal solution.

> Judging from the examples in the pdf it is already possible to some quite impressive editions with ConTeXt

If you're referring to p. 40-50 of the document you linked to: I produced those, and they are handcoded, not produced with any programmatical tools.

I'm slowly starting work on a style sheet that will allow me to typeset TEI xml in ConTeXt, and I hope that this may be useful to other users as well. But again: I'm doing this for my own work, and it is unlikely that this will be a solution for every imaginable critical edition.

Comment: I'm probably pampered by all the ready-to-use LaTeX-packages: I am more or less looking for an alternative to `ledmac/ledpar` and a "how-to" in the vein of their documentations. Though they are fantastic in many ways, they do have some [limitations and shortcomings](https://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/ledmac-users/2011-August/000035.html), where some (eg. the [limitation to two textflows](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2005-08/msg00498.html)) seem not to be solvable.

Comment: A native ConTeXt-solution would also allow me to make use of ConTeXt's additional features, xml-support being one of my top priorities. Therefore I'd be **very** interested to learn more about your work with TEI-integration. When you get around to publish anything on the subject, I'd appreciate it very much, if you would post a link here.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to login yesterday, so I can only post an answer, not a comment. Regarding TEI xml: have you seen the section on the ConTeXt wiki at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TEI_xml ? That should get you started.

Comment: @Thomas: I merged your two accounts and moved your other post to a comment here. You can now edit your answer post if you want. Please note that signatures should not be used. Your name is already added at the end of each post or comment. Thanks for your contribution and [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)